# Reactjs, reducers, language switching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reducers

I have just taken over a new reactjs project -- and I am trying to review how language switching has been invoked.

so like there are two links in the footer to do this language switch.

//footer.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { selectLanguage, getLangDetails } from '../../actions/action_language'
import langObject from './Footer.lang'

class Footer extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.changeLanguageToGerman = this.changeLanguageToGerman.bind(this)
    this.changeLanguageToEnglish = this.changeLanguageToEnglish.bind(this)
  } 

  changeLanguageToGerman () {
    this.props.selectLanguage('de')
  }

  changeLanguageToEnglish () {
    this.props.selectLanguage('en')
  } 

  render () {
    let activeLang = 'language--active'
    let alternativeLang = 'language--hover'
    const lang = getLangDetails(this.props.active_language, langObject)
    return (
      <div>
        <footer className='main-footer show-for-medium-only'>
          <div className='medium-15 columns'>
            <p className='text--white grid__row--offset--15 footer-text'>
              <Link to={this.props.deURL} className={`text--white footer-text ${this.props.active_language === 'de' ? activeLang : alternativeLang}`} onClick={this.changeLanguageToGerman}>DE</Link>
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&#124;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <Link to={this.props.enURL} className={`text--white footer-text ${this.props.active_language === 'en' ? activeLang : alternativeLang}`} onClick={this.changeLanguageToEnglish}>EN</Link>
            </p>
          </div>
        </footer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    active_language: state.active_language
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({selectLanguage: selectLanguage}, dispatch)
}

const { string, func } = React.PropTypes
Footer.propTypes = {
  deURL: string,
  enURL: string,
  selectLanguage: func,
  active_language: string
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Footer)
```

// header.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getLangDetails } from '../../actions/action_language'
import langObject from './Header.lang'

class Header extends React.Component {
  render () {
    let transparent
    transparent = this.props.transparent ? 'transparent' : ''
    const lang = getLangDetails(this.props.active_language, langObject)
    return (
      <div>
        <header className={` main_headerbar__landing transition show-for-large-up ${transparent} `}>
          <div className='contain-to-grid'>
            {lang}
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    active_language: state.active_language
  }
}

const { bool, string } = React.PropTypes
Header.propTypes = {
  transparent: bool,
  active_language: string
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header)
```

--- so these are the header/footer components - and each has a json file that splits into an array of lang.

there is a file that looks like some global js that I think hooks into this - but I am struggling to extend this functionality into the rest of the site components/pages

//action_language.js

```
export const LANGUAGE_SELECTED = 'LANGUAGE_SELECTED'

export function selectLanguage (language) {
  return {
    type: LANGUAGE_SELECTED,
    payload: language
  }
}

export function getLangDetails (language = 'de', langObject) {
  const langData = langObject.langs.filter((langVar) => langVar.lang === language)
  return langData['0'].lines
}
```

---

ok - so here is the first page -- called services. Now what throws me first here is rather than use active_language its now just language.

//services.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from '../HeaderLanding/Header'
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer'
import NoBundle from './NoBundle'
import HowTiles from './HowTiles'
import CarouselTiles from './CarouselTiles'
import YourAdvantages from './YourAdvantages'
import InformationTiles from './InformationTiles'
import ContactTiles from './ContactTiles'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { selectLanguage, getLangDetails } from '../../actions/action_language'

// language file
import langObject from './services.lang.json'

//  services css
import './services.css'

// getting the distinct URLs from the lang files
const deURL = langObject.langs[0].pageURL
const enURL = langObject.langs[1].pageURL

const Spacers = () => (
  <div>
    <div className='row show-for-large-up' style={{ height: '250px' }} />
    <div className='row show-for-medium-only' style={{ height: '150px' }} />
    <div className='row show-for-small-only' style={{ height: '80px' }} />
  </div>
)

class Services extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.language = props.match.params.langURL
  }
  componentWillMount () {
    document.getElementById('body').className = 'overlay-background-services'

    this.updateLanguage()
  }
  updateLanguage () {
    console.log('updatelang', this.language)
    if (this.language === 'de' || !this.language) {
      this.props.selectLanguage('de')
    } else {
      this.props.selectLanguage('en')
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount () {
    document.getElementById('body').className = ''
  }

  render () {
    const lang = getLangDetails(this.language, langObject)
    return (
      <div>
        <Header transparent />
        <Spacers />
        <NoBundle lang={lang} />
        <HowTiles />
        <CarouselTiles />
        <YourAdvantages />
        <InformationTiles />
        <ContactTiles />
        <Footer deURL={deURL} enURL={enURL} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    language: state.language
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({selectLanguage: selectLanguage}, dispatch)
}

const { func, string, object } = React.PropTypes
Services.propTypes = {
  selectLanguage: func,
  langURL: string,
  params: object,
  match: object
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Services)
```

Comment: can you be more specific about what you're struggling with? it's hard to answer your question because well.. you're not really asking a question yet

Comment: alright -- its a bit difficult to me to put it in a question. Essentially you have a switch that is invoked with two links in the footer -- so its going to cause a change in the language content for the footer -- using data from a json file. -- the header is picking up this change properly too. -- I suppose my first question is -- is this the best way of sorting this problem out - just focusing on the header/footer code -- 2nd question is carrying this logic throughout other parts of the site

Comment: your first question: without knowing anything else about your app i don't know.. but it seems sensible. your second question still isn't a question. maybe try doing it somewhere first.. maybe it will work, error or you will get stuck trying,. then come back and ask

Comment: The issue I am having - is I am starting to add similar logic handling into the component that handles an actual page -- its made up of smaller components -- it works fine on refreshing the page to that url -- but not updating on the switch

Comment: I think the mapStateToProps in my page file -- doesn't appear to update on a change -- not like the header/footer

Comment: can you post the code you tried to write? that would be the easiest way to see what you're doing wrong, if anything.

Comment: sure - ok check out the services.js -- it uses an updateLanguage function -- has componentWillMount and constructor functions... -- is it including the header/footer as an include and some kind of out of scope problem?

Comment: ** the problem here -- is it works when the page is refreshed -- but not when clicking the links at the bottom -- like it just re-renders the service.js -- without getting the new language parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The Footer component deals with setting the current language by invoking the Redux action creator `selectLanguage`. Essentially this dispatches an action (you can think of this as a custom event with some corresponding data - the language) to the store that will persist the user's language selection for use elsewhere.

In order to consume the language in other components, that language selection needs to be passed into the component (in this case the Header) from the Redux store.

This is the code of interest in header that does that...

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    active_language: state.active_language
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header)
```

Here you are connecting the Header to the store, with a function that describes how the store should map values into props on your react component. `state.active_language` is where the language that the user has selected is stored, and this is telling it to be passed as a prop called `active_language` on your Header component

The `connect` function is a decorator that will create what's know as a Higher Order Component (HOC) which is essentially a component with props or functionality automatically injected into it (decorated in this case with an automatically passed value for the `active_language` prop from the store)

You can do the same for any other component that need this language setting, or go a step or two further

Instead of passing the active language name, pass the corresponding language itself...

```
import { getLangDetails } from '../../actions/action_language'
import langObject from './Header.lang'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    active_language: getLangDetails(state.active_language, langObject)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header)
```

OR better yet write another HOC that wraps any component you pass with this info...

```
import { getLangDetails } from '../../actions/action_language'

export default const injectLanguage = (component, langObject) => connect((state) => ({
    language: getLangDetails(state.active_language, langObject)
  })
)(component)
```

Then in subsequent components with a `language` prop, decorate with this

```
import injectLanguage from './some/where'
import langObject from './MyLanguageDetailsAwareComponent.lang'

class MyLanguageDetailsAwareComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return this.props.language
  }

}

export default injectLanguage(MyLanguageDetailsAwareComponent, langObject)
```

Comment: Hello @alechill I've updated the question - to show you the issue I'm having switching the language on the core part of the page -- service.js

Comment: Looks like it's being passed in via the store props as `language` and never used, and also from a route or something that gets matched and then resets the store value to whatever was matched in the route on every component update, totally ignoring and overriding the store. It seems your page and footer selector is working against each other with the page winning

Comment: A change to `this.language = props.language || props.match.params.langURL` would prefer the store setting if user has already set it, but would default it to the language in what I presume is the route on first time use I think. Sorry I'm on phone now so these aren't too detailed

Comment: --these are good ideas - I will try and look into this properly tomorrow myself -- I didn't write this code so its a bit difficult for me to reverse engineer too -- I tried to do something like props.language - but that's a mistake as its a read-only state by that point.

Comment: I've added your code to the project -- but it looks like props.language is ALWAYS undefined--- and also when the link is clicked -- it never invokes the constructor again so this.language I don't think favors that props.language -- to be honest though - it looks like props.language is always never set?

Comment: In constructor it very likely would be undefined as if it's a page definition you won't have had chance to change language yet. Move `
this.updateLanguage()` into constructor instead of in willupdate and use `const lang = getLangDetails(this.props.language, langObject)` in render instead

Comment: tried that -- looks like this.props.language is always undefined

Comment: Ahhhh, of course, according to Footer  it should map to state.active_language. Check reducers for the correct state property to map to and use it in both

Comment: I was looking at this -- cause its looking for state.language in this service.js -- const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('state', state)
  return {
    language: state.language
  }
}

Comment: but when I switch over to active_language -- I think that too is set to null and so it again borks at finding the default array position to go to -- because it doesn't have any value - en or gb